# If statements always passing to else statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm working on a simple password storage console application in c#.

I'm having a bit of a problem on a section that asks if the user would like to mask all password entries from that point on.

This is the section of code:

```
bool tryagain = true;
while(tryagain == true)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Would you like to mask all other password  entiries?(Y,N)");
  string input = Console.ReadLine();
  if (input == "y" | input == "Y")
  //Something wrong, always passes to Your awnser was invalid
  {
      maskpass = true;
      tryagain = false;
  }

  if (input == "n" | input == "N")
  {
      maskpass = false;
      tryagain = false;
  }
  else
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Your awnser was invalid, would you like to try again?");
      string yesno = Console.ReadLine();
      if (yesno == "y" | yesno == "Y")
      {
          tryagain = true;
      }

      if (yesno == "n" | yesno == "N")
      {
          Environment.Exit(0);
      }
  }
}
```

The problem is when I run the code it always runs to the else statement.

I'm certain the mistake is very simple and I'm just being ignorant but anyone have any idea on whats going on here?

Comment: if you want to perform an OR do not use a single | but you have to use double || , e.g.
`input == "y" || input == "Y"`

Comment: @juergend How would that help..?

Answer (score 7):

Use `||` instead of single `|`. The `||` mean **or** conditional, but single `|` is *binary or*.

I *assume* that the logic of your code says:

`if input=='y' OR input=="Y"`, do something.

Another suggession yet. If my assumption right, you can achiev that with simple [String.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/c64xh8f9.aspx) overload:

```
if(input.Equals("y", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
{
   //do something/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use || or you can use the method of the String class String.equals. Since it is a String you are reading as input better use the String.equals method